# calling function inside a another function

Tags: javascript

```
S.ui.createpulldown = function() {  
    function someName(){
    }
    someName() // gets called
}
someName() // does not get called, when outside because of scope issue.
```

I want to call this function outside the `s.ui.createpulldown` function. Is it possible, on what changes i have to make to `function someName()`

Comment: Why don't you defined `someName` outside  then?

Answer (score 3):

you have to assign the function to a variable that is visible in the desired scope :

```
//...
var someName;
S.ui.createpulldown = function() {  

  someName = function(){

  }

  someName() // gets called

}
someName(); // gets called also
//...
```

or if you want it to be a global variable (visible in all scopes), you can pin it to the window object :

```
window.someName = function(){};
```

Note that this will work only after the execution of the `S.ui.createpulldown` function (thx,  pimvdb).

Comment: As it stands it won't get called. You'd have to execute `createpulldown` first.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scoping problem. You can't access `somefunction` because it is a local variable of `createPullDown`, just like `i` in the following example

```
function pulldown(){
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){ ... }
}

i; //can't use "i" here!
```

If you want `somename` to ve visible outside the function you need to declare it outside, or pass it to someone that is visible outside or set a property of an object that is visible outside;

```
var someFunction;
var someObj = {};

S.ui.createpulldown = function() {  

   function someName(){

   }

   someFunction = someName;
   someObj.func = someName;

}

S.ui.createpulldown();

someFunction();
someObj.func();
```

Comment: If the someName() function has another onload function... that is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

move `somename` outside the function in which it is defined.  If you are going to use it in more than one place, put it on the appropriate part of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function `someName()` outside the `s.ui.createpulldown` function.